# System.AssertEquals Issues in deploying to production

Tags: apex

I've been searching the Salesforce Developer forum and StackExchange and can't figure out what the issue is with my deployment to production that keeps failing. When I run the test in the sandbox, it passes but when trying to deploy the code into production, it continues to fail on this line:

```
system.assertEquals('cmlam.com,sky.com', cynthiaMNYC.Email_Domains__c);
```

I have put *** around the line below to help you see. I know that querying the object is necessary for System.AssertEquals so I've already done that. Any other ideas?

I am still new to coding so please forgive me for any rookie mistakes.

### Test Class

```
@isTest
public class ContactTrigger_tests {

    public static testmethod void updateAccountEmailDomains_test(){
        
        Id pubAccountRTId = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Publisher').getRecordTypeId();
        Id pubContactRTId = Schema.SObjectType.Contact.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Publisher Contact').getRecordTypeId();
        
        //initialize data
        Account cynthiaMNYC = new Account(Name = 'Anthem', BillingCountry = 'US', BillingState = 'CA',Email_Domain_Exception_Account__c = false, RecordTypeId = pubAccountRTId, 
                                          Website = 'www.cynthiamnyc.com', Account_Tier__c = 'Non-Key', Customer_Segment__c = 'Elastic', Email_Domains__c = '');
        insert cynthiaMNYC;
        Account skyCompany = new Account(Name = 'Synergy', BillingCountry = 'US', BillingState = 'CA', Email_Domain_Exception_Account__c = false, RecordTypeId = pubAccountRTId,
                                        Website = 'www.skycompany.com', Account_Tier__c = 'Non-Key', Customer_Segment__c = 'Elastic', Email_Domains__c = '');
        insert skyCompany;        
        
        test.startTest();

        Contact c = new Contact(LastName = 'CM Lam', Email = 'cmlam@cmlam.com', AccountId = cynthiaMNYC.Id, MailingCountry = 'US', MailingState = 'CA', RecordTypeId = pubContactRTId);
        Contact c2 = new Contact(LastName = 'Stephanie Kry', Email = 'skry@sky.com', AccountId = cynthiaMNYC.Id, MailingCountry = 'US', MailingState = 'CA', RecordTypeId = pubContactRTId);        
        List<Contact> contactList = new List<Contact>();
        contactList.add(c);
        contactList.add(c2);
        insert contactList;
        
        c = [SELECT Email FROM Contact WHERE Id = :c.id];
        c2 = [SELECT Email FROM Contact WHERE Id = :c2.id];
        
        cynthiaMNYC = [SELECT Email_Domains__c FROM Account WHERE Id = :cynthiaMNYC.Id];
        ***system.assertEquals('cmlam.com,sky.com', cynthiaMNYC.Email_Domains__c);***
        
        
        //test delete case
        delete c2;
        cynthiaMNYC = [SELECT Email_Domains__c FROM Account WHERE Id = :cynthiaMNYC.Id];
        system.assertEquals('cmlam.com', cynthiaMNYC.Email_Domains__c);
        
        //test undelete case
        undelete c2;
        cynthiaMNYC = [SELECT Email_Domains__c FROM Account WHERE Id = :cynthiaMNYC.Id];
        system.assertEquals('cmlam.com,sky.com', cynthiaMNYC.Email_Domains__c);
        
        //test update email case
        c.Email = 'test12345@testdomain789.com';
        update c;
        cynthiaMNYC = [SELECT Email_Domains__c FROM Account WHERE Id = :cynthiaMNYC.Id];
        system.assertEquals('testdomain789.com,sky.com', cynthiaMNYC.Email_Domains__c);        
        
        //test update parent account case        
        c2.AccountId = skyCompany.Id;
        update c2;
        cynthiaMNYC = [SELECT Email_Domains__c FROM Account WHERE Id = :cynthiaMNYC.Id];
        system.assertEquals('testdomain789.com', cynthiaMNYC.Email_Domains__c);                
        skyCompany = [SELECT Email_Domains__c FROM Account WHERE Id = :skyCompany.Id];
        system.assertEquals('sky.com', skyCompany.Email_Domains__c);  
        
        test.stopTest();
    }        
    
}
```

### Trigger

```
trigger ContactTriggers on Contact (after insert, after update, after delete, after undelete) {

    if(trigger.isAfter){
        if(trigger.isInsert){
            Contact_Trigger_Handlers.processContactEmailDomains(trigger.new);
        }
        else if(trigger.isUpdate){
            List<Contact> contactEmailsUpdateList = new List<Contact>();
            Set<Id> otherAccountIds = new Set<Id>(); //track accounts that have their contacts reassigned
            for(Contact c: trigger.new){
                if(c.Email != NULL && c.Email_Domain_Exception__c == false && c.Email_Domain__c != trigger.oldMap.get(c.Id).Email_Domain__c ){
                    contactEmailsUpdateList.add(c);
                }
                else if(c.Email != NULL && c.Email_Domain_Exception__c == false && c.AccountId != trigger.oldMap.get(c.Id).AccountId){
                    otherAccountIds.add(trigger.oldMap.get(c.Id).AccountId);
                    otherAccountIds.add(c.accountId);
                }                                       
            }
            if(!contactEmailsUpdateList.isEmpty()){
                Contact_Trigger_Handlers.processContactEmailDomains(contactEmailsUpdateList);                
            }
            if(!otherAccountIds.isEmpty()){
                Contact_Trigger_Handlers.updateAccountEmailDomains(otherAccountIds);
            }
        }
        else if(trigger.isDelete){
            Contact_Trigger_Handlers.processContactEmailDomains(trigger.old);
        }
        else if(trigger.isUndelete){
            Contact_Trigger_Handlers.processContactEmailDomains(trigger.new);        
        }                        
    }


}
```

### Trigger Handler

```
    public class Contact_Trigger_Handlers {

    public static void processContactEmailDomains(List<Contact> contactList){
        Set<Id> accountIdSet = new Set<Id>();
        for(Contact c: contactList){
            accountIdSet.add(c.AccountId);
        }
        if(!accountIdSet.isEmpty()){
            updateAccountEmailDomains(accountIdSet);
        }
    }

    public static void updateAccountEmailDomains(Set<Id> accountIdSet){
        Map<String, Excluded_Email_Domains__c> excludedDomainsMap = Excluded_Email_Domains__c.getAll();
        List<Account> accountsToUpdate = new List<Account>();        
        for(Account a: [SELECT Id, Email_Domains__c,
                       (SELECT Email_Domain__c, Email_Domain_Exception__c, Email FROM Contacts WHERE Email != null) 
                        FROM Account WHERE Id IN :accountIdSet]){
            Set<string> emailDomainSet = new Set<string>();
            for(Contact c: a.Contacts){
                if(c.Email != NULL && c.Email_Domain_Exception__c == false && !excludedDomainsMap.containsKey(c.Email_Domain__c) ){
                    emailDomainSet.add(c.Email_Domain__c);
                }                    
            }
            if(!emailDomainSet.isEmpty()){
                string emailDomainJoined = stringJoinSet(emailDomainSet);
                if (a.Email_Domains__c != emailDomainJoined) {
                    a.Email_Domains__c = emailDomainJoined;
                    accountsToUpdate.add(a);
                }
            }                                           
        }
        if(!accountsToUpdate.isEmpty()){
            try{
                update accountsToUpdate;
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                system.debug('Exception occurred attempting to update Account Email Domains---'+ e.getMessage());
            }
        }        
    }
    
    private static String stringJoinSet(Set<String> values) {
        List<String> valueCopy = new List<String>(values);
        if(valueCopy.isEmpty())
        return null;
        String result = valueCopy[0];
        valueCopy.remove(0);
        while(!valueCopy.isEmpty()) {
            result += ',' + valueCopy[0];
            valueCopy.remove(0);
        }
        return result;
    }  
    
    
}
```

### New Test Class Separated

```
@isTest
public class ContactTrigger_tests {
    
    @testSetup static void initialSetup(){
        
        Id pubAccountRTId = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Publisher').getRecordTypeId();
        Id pubContactRTId = Schema.SObjectType.Contact.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Publisher Contact').getRecordTypeId();
        
        //initialize data
        Account cynthiaMNYC = new Account(Name = 'Anthem', BillingCountry = 'US', BillingState = 'CA',Email_Domain_Exception_Account__c = false, RecordTypeId = pubAccountRTId, 
                                          Website = 'www.cynthiamnyc.com', Account_Tier__c = 'Non-Key', Customer_Segment__c = 'Elastic', Email_Domains__c = '');
        
        Account skyCompany = new Account(Name = 'Synergy', BillingCountry = 'US', BillingState = 'CA', Email_Domain_Exception_Account__c = false, RecordTypeId = pubAccountRTId,
                                         Website = 'www.skycompany.com', Account_Tier__c = 'Non-Key', Customer_Segment__c = 'Elastic', Email_Domains__c = '');
        
        List<Account> testAccts = new List<Account>();
        testAccts.add(cynthiaMNYC);
        testAccts.add(skyCompany);
        insert testAccts; 
        
        Contact c = new Contact(LastName = 'CM Lam', Email = 'cmlam@cmlam.com', AccountId = cynthiaMNYC.Id, MailingCountry = 'US', MailingState = 'CA', RecordTypeId = pubContactRTId);
        Contact c2 = new Contact(LastName = 'Stephanie Kry', Email = 'skry@sky.com', AccountId = cynthiaMNYC.Id, MailingCountry = 'US', MailingState = 'CA', RecordTypeId = pubContactRTId);        
        
        List<Contact> contactList = new List<Contact>();
        contactList.add(c);
        contactList.add(c2);
        insert contactList;
    }
    
    @isTest static void updateTestMethod() {
        // Get the first test account by using a SOQL query
        
        Contact ctc = [SELECT Id, Email FROM Contact WHERE Name = 'CM Lam']; 
        Account acct = [SELECT Id, Email_Domains__c FROM Account WHERE Name = 'Anthem'];
        
        //ctc.Email = 'cmlam@nativo.com';
        //update ctc;
       
        try { 
            // for inside
             for (Contact con : [SELECT Id, Email FROM Contact WHERE Name = 'CM Lam']) {
                Contact newCon = new Contact(
                Id = con.Id,
                Email = 'cmlam@nativo.com');
                update newCon ;
            }
        } catch (DmlException e) {
            System.debug(e.getMessage());
        }

        system.debug(ctc.Email);
        
        system.debug(acct.Email_Domains__c);
        
        system.assertEquals('nativo.com,sky.com', acct.Email_Domains__c);
    }
    
    @isTest static void deleteundeleteTestMethod1(){
        
        Contact ctc = [SELECT Id, Email FROM Contact WHERE Name = 'CM Lam'];
        Account acct = [SELECT Id, Email_Domains__c FROM Account WHERE Name = 'Anthem'];
        
        delete ctc; 
        system.assertEquals('sky.com', acct.Email_Domains__c);
        
        undelete ctc; 
        system.assertEquals('cmlam.com,sky.com', acct.Email_Domains__c);
    }
    
    @isTest static void initialtestMethod(){
        Account acct = [SELECT Id, Email_Domains__c FROM Account WHERE Name = 'Anthem'];
        
        system.assertEquals('cmlam.com,sky.com', acct.Email_Domains__c);
    }
    @isTest static void reparenttestMethod(){
        Account acct = [SELECT Id, Email_Domains__c FROM Account WHERE Name = 'Synergy'];
        Contact ctc = [SELECt Id, Email FROM Contact WHERE Name = 'CM Lam'];
        Contact ctc2 = [SELECT Id, Email FROM Contact WHERE Name = 'Stephanie Kry'];
        
        ctc.AccountId = acct.id; 
        update ctc; 
        
        system.assertEquals('cmlam.com,sky.com', acct.Email_Domains__c);
    }
}
```

Comment: what does the trigger look like which populates `Email_Domains__c` on Account? Did you also include this trigger on `Contact` in your deployment to production?

Comment: Have Sandbox and Prod the same Validation Rules, Processes in PB, maybe Record Triggered Flows?, Also can you please provide your trigger code.

Comment: in the assertion error - what is the value of `cynthiaMNYC.Email_Domains__c`?

Comment: @MarkPond I included the trigger in my deployment. I edited my original question to include the Trigger and Trigger Handler so you can see my Trigger.

Comment: @AjFmO The trigger code has been updated.

Comment: @cropredy The value is null.

Comment: Few suggestions, separate your test scenarios, delete and undelete under a single test, and all other the same, use TestSetup as suggested in the answer below. Ran a test in the Anonimous Apex Console, check if it works as expected.

Comment: @AjFmO Thanks for formatting my code to make it more readable. I foolishly didn't even realize you could do that. I added the testsetup in the above question but I'm still getting error messages on every system.assertequals. In the deleteundelete method, I see:System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected: sky.com, Actual: cmlam.com,sky.com. On the reparenttestMethods, I see System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected: cmlam.com,sky.com, Actual: null. On the updateTestMethod, I see System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected: nativo.com,sky.com, Actual: cmlam.com,sky.com.

Comment: @AjFmO I added the try catch and I'm still not getting the expected result. In fact, the system.debug isn't even recognizing that the contact's email was updated. It is still returning the old email cmlam@cmlam.com.

Comment: @pluginbaby I'm still in a meeting, at the same time replicating your settings, ping me on linkedin, I'm trying to set up the custom settings.

Comment: @AjFmO ok thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The changes are being made after insert/updates/deletes, but you are comparing with the Account values before those changes are committed, you would need to change the order, get the account after the changes, and compare against this updated Account.

To help you a bit more here's the updated code.

```
public class ContactTrigger_tests {

    @TestSetup
    static void initialSetup() {

        Id pubAccountRTId = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Publisher').getRecordTypeId();
        Id pubContactRTId = Schema.SObjectType.Contact.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Publisher Contact').getRecordTypeId();

        //initialize data
        Account cynthiaMNYC = new Account(
                Name = 'Anthem',
                BillingCountry = 'US',
                BillingState = 'CA',
                Email_Domain_Exception_Account__c = false,
                RecordTypeId = pubAccountRTId,
                Website = 'www.cynthiamnyc.com',
                Account_Tier__c = 'Non-Key',
                Customer_Segment__c = 'Elastic',
                Email_Domains__c = ''
        );

        Account skyCompany = new Account(
                Name = 'Synergy',
                BillingCountry = 'US',
                BillingState = 'CA',
                Email_Domain_Exception_Account__c = false,
                RecordTypeId = pubAccountRTId,
                Website = 'www.skycompany.com',
                Account_Tier__c = 'Non-Key',
                Customer_Segment__c = 'Elastic',
                Email_Domains__c = ''
        );

        List<Account> testAccts = new List<Account>();
        testAccts.add(cynthiaMNYC);
        testAccts.add(skyCompany);
        insert testAccts;

        Contact c = new Contact(
                LastName = 'CM Lam',
                Email = 'cmlam@cmlam.com',
                AccountId = cynthiaMNYC.Id,
                MailingCountry = 'US',
                MailingState = 'CA',
                RecordTypeId = pubContactRTId
        );
        Contact c2 = new Contact(
                LastName = 'Stephanie Kry',
                Email = 'skry@sky.com',
                AccountId = cynthiaMNYC.Id,
                MailingCountry = 'US',
                MailingState = 'CA',
                RecordTypeId = pubContactRTId
        );

        List<Contact> contactList = new List<Contact>();
        contactList.add(c);
        contactList.add(c2);
        insert contactList;
    }

    @IsTest
    static void updateTestMethod() {
        // Get the first test account by using a SOQL query

        Contact con = [SELECT Id, Email FROM Contact WHERE Name = 'CM Lam'];
        con.Email = 'cmlam@nativo.com';
        update con;

        Account acct = [SELECT Id, Email_Domains__c FROM Account WHERE Name = 'Anthem'];
        System.assertEquals('nativo.com,sky.com', acct.Email_Domains__c);
    }

    @IsTest
    static void deleteUndeleteTestMethod1() {
        Contact ctc = [SELECT Id, Email FROM Contact WHERE Name = 'CM Lam'];

        delete ctc;
        Account acct1 = [SELECT Id, Email_Domains__c FROM Account WHERE Name = 'Anthem'];
        System.assertEquals('sky.com', acct1.Email_Domains__c);

        undelete ctc;
        Account acct2 = [SELECT Id, Email_Domains__c FROM Account WHERE Name = 'Anthem'];
        System.assertEquals('cmlam.com,sky.com', acct2.Email_Domains__c);
    }


    @IsTest
    static void initialTestMethod() {
        Account acct = [SELECT Id, Email_Domains__c FROM Account WHERE Name = 'Anthem'];
        System.assertEquals('cmlam.com,sky.com', acct.Email_Domains__c);
    }

    @IsTest
    static void reparentTestMethod() {
        Account acctB4 = [SELECT Id, Email_Domains__c FROM Account WHERE Name = 'Synergy'];
        Contact ctc = [SELECT Id, Email FROM Contact WHERE Name = 'CM Lam'];
        Contact ctc2 = [SELECT Id, Email FROM Contact WHERE Name = 'Stephanie Kry'];

        List<Contact> contacts2Update = new List<Contact>();
        ctc.AccountId = acctB4.Id;
        ctc2.AccountId = acctB4.Id;
        contacts2Update.add(ctc);
        contacts2Update.add(ctc2);
        update contacts2Update;

        Account acctAfter = [SELECT Id, Email_Domains__c FROM Account WHERE Name = 'Synergy'];
        System.assertEquals('cmlam.com,sky.com', acctAfter.Email_Domains__c);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Based on the code I am seeing I am only seeing you set Email_Domains__c to ''. You create cynthiaMNYC account beneath comment //initialize data and then use that same variable id to get the data you just inserted before the assert so I am not seeing how this even would work on a sandbox.¯_(ツ)_/¯

As a side note I suggest you use @testsetup as described at below link to separate your concerns of preparation of data to your actual tests FYI.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_testsetup_using.htm